# Defining functions in a module and calling them from a controller

Tags: 8, page-controller

I want to use a function in both a controller and a module. where should I define that function?

Can I call a function in module from a controller? How I can do that?

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly the case when you define a Service:

- In your controller you call the service with Dependency injection
- In your module you call the static \Drupal::service('..')

Comment: This is recommend yes, but you can always also call any function in a .module file, they are always loaded.

Answer (score 1):

First off, a controller is just an instance of a class. As such, calling a function from a controller is not different from what you would do in another PHP class. To answer your questions:

- *Where should I define that function?* You can define it in the module file, since that is already loaded when a controller object is created and its methods are called.
- *Can I call a function in module from a controller? How I can do that?* Yes, you can, and you don't need to do something more than calling the function as you would call it from another function, since modules are already loaded when a controller object is created.

Comparing a single function with a [service](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/group/container/8.2.x) doesn't make much sense; you will never replace a function like [`taxonomy_get_title()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_title/8.2.x) with a service. I would rather compare a service with a group of related function, and in that case, I would say that a service is preferable to a group of related functions.

- A service has the same [vantages of using a class instead of a group of functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285404/why-should-i-use-classes-rather-than-just-a-collection-of-functions)
- A service gets its dependencies injected, which makes easier to test it than testing a group of functions